# How to add a new line in the middle of string in c#

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I have the following string which contains reviews for products, I want to move sentences like 1 of 3 and 4 of 13 into new lines

Input string

```
The mapping features have a lot of inaccuracie 1 of 3
am a little disappointed in the new 4S. 4 of 13
```

Output string

```
The mapping features have a lot of inaccuracies 
1 of 3
am a little disappointed in the new 4S 
4 of 13
```

I was trying `Regex.Replace` because it changes all occurrences in the string

I located the string using `@"\d+ of \d+"`

but how can I keep the variable number in the replacement text? Or can you suggest a different method?

Answer (score 2):

You need to *capture* the match in order to be able to use it for replacement:

```
@"(\d+ of \d+)"
```

To replace this value, use `$1`.

Something like:

```
Regex.Replace(input, 
              @"(\d+ of \d+)", 
              string.Format(@"{0}$1{0}", Environment.NewLine))
```

Comment: this command deleted the original text (1 of 3) and replaced it by \1. I want to keep the numbers and just add new line before them

Comment: @ahmadjawdat - Sorry for that - I got the backreference syntax wrong. It is `$1` for the first capturing parens instead of `\1`. Answer updated.